# Using a icon aside a text

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to put this icons aside the texts, but i dont know how.

This is the HTML:

```
    <section class="info">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <span class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-5x"></span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elit </p>
                <span class="fa fa-credit-card fa-5x"></span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elit </p>
                <span class="fa fa-calendar fa-5x"></span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elit </p>
            </div>
    </section>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.info {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f98835;
}

.info .row {
  margin: 30px 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.info .row .fa {
  color: black;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.info .row p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}
```

I was trying to use float: left in the text, but is breaking..

[image]

Comment: Use `clear:both` on the text paragraphs.

Comment: I'd just assign each icon (from a single CSS sprite image - http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) as `:after` pseudo-classes to each paragraph.

Comment: Put the icons inside of the paragraphs, not outside and put a float: left on them. Clearing would also do the trick as @amphetamachine said.

Comment: you're missing your col- classes

Answer (score 0):

Add the float to the `fa` class:

```
.info .row .fa {
  color: black;
  margin: 20px 0;
  float: left;
  clear: both; /* may not be necessary */
}
```

But logically, I would place the `span.fa` element within the paragraph element, in which case the clear should be moved to the p: `.info .row p { clear:both; }`.

Comment: put the span.fa inside the p will work, but its very ugly, look:http://i.imgur.com/v83CJn6.png @sebnuken

Answer (score 0):

Add float: left and a width to your .fa class.  You can use the col classes to do this for you.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/ogp6981z/)

**CSS:**

```
.info { 
    background-color: #f98835;
    padding: 30px 0 100px;
    color: #fff;
}
.info .fa {
    color: #000;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section class="info">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 text-center">
                <span class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-5x"></span>
            </div>
            <p class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-lg-11">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elit</p>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 text-center">
                <span class="fa fa-credit-card fa-5x"></span>
            </div>
            <p class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-lg-11">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elit</p>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 text-center">
                <span class="fa fa-calendar fa-5x"></span>
            </div>
            <p class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-lg-11">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elit</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

In the CSS, you don't need to set the width of the .info class to 100% because the section element is a block-level element.  Moreover, adding padding to the section eliminates the need for the margin on the row and the last-child p element (as last-child is not supported in IE8).  Finally, you can remove the text-align: left; since that is the default behavior of paragraphs (unless you've overridden that elsewhere in your css).

In your markup, don't forget to add at least one col class to every row.  If you want only one full width column at every breakpoint, then just use col-xs-12.  For viewports less that 768px, I made the icon stack.  You can change that by setting the col-xs to something other than 12, but you'll probably need to set up some media queries to resize your icon accordingly.